# How does the user set geometry in a class that loads fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, documentclass-writing

In my class, I defined the header style with `fancyhdr`. This causes trouble when the user wishes to modify the geometry settings, since `geometry` configuration should happen before `fancyhdr`.

Below is an example. The class is named `myclass`:

```
%% myclass.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\def\myclass@baseclass{article}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
    family = @myclass,
    prefix = @myclass@
}
\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\myclass@baseclass}}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax
\LoadClass{\myclass@baseclass}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

And the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=1in}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

One would get:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can load fancyhdr but delay using the `\fancy...` commands in an `\AtBeginDocument{...` so they happen after the user preamble

Comment: you could call `\fancyhfoffset{0pt}` at the end  of the preamble.